# How can I add same text to each item of the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list:
`a=['c1','c2','c3']`
And I would like to get to:
`b=[sametext['c1'],sametext['c2'],sametext['c3']]`

I've tried to make list in list but I'm not able to get any result? How can I get to b?

Comment: what is `sametext`? Show a full reproducible example please

Comment: What does it matter what sometext is? It is irrelevant, some text is sometext because that it is some text. You download a question because you don't understand it?

Comment: I meant what type of python object is `sametext`? e.g. a string, list or dict. You should always show a small example if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `[sametext['c1'],sametext['c2'],sametext['c3']]`, is sametext a dictionary which contains a mapping of some sort?
If that's the case then the way to do it will be with this list comprehension:

```
b = [sametext[x] for x in a]
```

Without list comprehensions:

```
b=[]
for x in a:
   b.append(sametext[x])
```

If by sametext all you mean is some constant operation, like adding a prefix then similar to the first approach the way would be:

```
b = [f"yourprefix_{x}]" for x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b= [ele+'some_text' for ele in a]
```

To make change in-place

```
a[:] = [ele+'some_text' for ele in a]
```